# Check if Text Field NEARLY Matches Set Text? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone now how I can check if a text field NEARLY matches a set text?

I know how to check if it exactly matches, but i want it to know if its even close to the set text

So if they type HELLO WORD it indicates its close but not exact match?

```
if (([textfield.text isEqual:@"HELLO WORLD"]))
{
    NSLog(@"Correct");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Please specify the definition of "nearly matches". This is programming, not poetry

Comment: @nobbsy, when you say nearly matches then in this case you have to compare the range of text using NSRange. Did you try??

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

[This library](https://github.com/thetron/StringScore) may be of use to you. And since it's open source, you can check the source to see how it's done. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

**For Case Insensitive :**

```
if( [textfield.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"My Case sensitiVE"] == NSOrderedSame )  {   
    // strings are equal except for possibly case 
}
```

**For Case Sensitive :**

```
if([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"My Case sensitiVE"]) {  
    // Case sensitive Compare 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
NSString caseInsensitiveCompare:
```

**or**

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString 
                      options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each index of two string and see how many difference is there. And you should define your "nearly match", it may be difference in single character or in multiple character. And decide if you should accept it or reject it.

If you like algorithm [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) is a key to your goal.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"HELLO WORLD I AM JACK";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"HELLO WORLD"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain HELLO WORLD");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains HELLO WORLD!");
}
```